# What kind of projection is this?

Tags: coordinate-system

Can someone tell me what the projection is in [this zone map from NOAA](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/om/marine/zone/hsmz.htm)?

[image: Figure: Reduced map image]

I am trying to replicate it (or get close) in QGIS.

Comment: how much information do you want?  It's mercator of some sort...

Comment: Looks like a Geographic coordinate system with WGS1984 datum, BUT visual prescription of projections is not really the best way to determine a projection. If you go to the target page and at the actual page where you find the data the coordinate system will usually also be provided.

Comment: @mr.adam can't be Mercator, it has degrees as unit

Comment: @yanes the degree grid changes size, and Greenland appears to be larger than So. America, so Mercator isn't a bad guess.

Comment: @yanes The map is annotated with a graticule (latitude and longitude lines) with labels. That doesn't mean that the map itself is in latitude-longitude.

Comment: It's possible but with all the annotations given in degrees it is more straight forward to assume it is a GCS. I can't pan on it, when clicked it goes to the National Weather Service page, So you can't see the whole Greenland in context to  North America.  In anyway, it is safest to consult the publishers as PolyGeo suggested.

Comment: ok, as per your comment, try using web mercator as your project CRS.  You can search for it in QGIS by using the EPSG code 3857 (it's called WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator.  You'll find it to look about the same as this map.

Answer (score 7):

The best people to ask are the publishers of that web map.

The [Contacts](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/om/marine/phone.htm) button offers an email address (and phone number) for General Enquiries, as well as many other types of contacts.

Answer (score 3):

It is a Mercator projection, with standard latitude near the Equator.

This conclusion takes two steps:

1. **Recognize the nature of the projection.** This one is cylindrical: small dashed white lines, running vertically and horizontally, display the *graticule* corresponding to lines of longitude and latitude, respectively.  This orthogonal grid indicates the projection is *cylindrical.*
2. **Quantify the distance distortion.**

   - It is visually evident this map provides a constant scale along the Equator, because the longitudes are equally spaced.  (Digitizing the image to find the coordinates verifies this: on my screen they are spaced by 57.8 pixels, with a standard error of 0.6 pixels.)
   - By digitizing the y-coordinates of the horizontal lines in the graticule, we can fit a least-squares model to relate these coordinates to the corresponding y-coordinates of any projection.  Using the Mercator projection gave a beautifully linear fit (all the residuals were smaller than one pixel in the image) for all latitudes shown, from -30 to +70 degrees.

Comparing the coefficients in the least-squares fits performed in step (2) indicates the vertical scale at the Equator is approximately 1.005 times the horizontal scale at the Equator: essentially 1:1.  That means the latitude of true scale is the Equator.

You will need to figure out an appropriate origin and constant scale factor to apply in order to match this image with any QGIS features.  Your numbers may differ from mine (which were based on a cropped screen shot).